# Mysql complicated join, anyone?

Tags: mysql

I need to write a query like this, any help please?

```
select id, parent, faq, 
(select count(*) from faq_table where parent = 
(select id from faq_questions) group by id) 
 as reply from faq_table
```

This table stores questions and answers (like a FAQ thing), and answers get the value of it's question's ID in the column of parent. Ideally, I would also like to add a second column called par, where all questions will get a value of 1.

**Like:**

```
id  | parent | faq
19  |    0   | name a president of the US
20  |   19   | Bush
21  |   19   | Obama
22  |    0   | Can Canada win the WC match against the Lankan's today
23  |   22   | Yes because Cheema is going to make a double today
```

In the resulting table out of that query, I must get:

```
id  | parent | faq  |  reply | par
19  |   0    | name a president of the US | 2 | 1
20  |  19    | Bush  | 0 | 0
21  |  19    | Obama | 0 | 0
22  |   0    | Can Canada win the WC match against the Lankan's today | 1 | 1
23  |  22    | Yes because Cheema is going to make a double today | 0 | 0
```

Comment: Can you add your complete table structure ie two source tables also and the foreign key

Comment: thanks exp. I have only one source table here, faq_table, with id being the primary key, no foreign key

Comment: So you have a single table storing both questions and answers. And how are you letting others answer it?

Comment: I think you got serious problem in your db structure in `faq` are you storing both question and answer?

Comment: @experimentX yes, i'm storing both question and answers in the same table. That's the standard way to go, isn't it, in case later we need to have multiple levels of answers. Same way as we do menus and submenus in the same table, we don't create a new table for each submenu level. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will only work for a single hierarchy level:

```
SELECT t.id, t.parent, t.faq, IFNULL(g.Cnt, 0) as reply,
  g.Cnt IS NOT NULL AS par
FROM faq_table t LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT parent, COUNT(*) Cnt
    FROM faq_table
    WHERE parent > 0
    GROUP BY parent
  ) g ON t.id = g.parent
```

Otherwise, you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT t.id, t.parent, t.faq,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM faq_table f WHERE f.parent = t.id) as reply,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM faq_table f WHERE f.parent = t.id) > 0 As par
FROM faq_table t
```

Comment: The first option seems to return the results the wrong way round - the counts are against the answers, not the questions...

Comment: Yes, the second option works better (and way too easy to understand for mortals compared to the first one ;))

Comment: @The Scrum Meistern by the way is there any basic difference between these two, performance wise, for big tables?

Comment: @jeremy-roy First query will perform better, since it will scan the table only once to get the counts. The second option will scan the table (or indexes) once for every row.

Comment: @The Scrum Meister, ah thanks for clarifying, in my very small table, I have just checked, your first solution was thrice as fast. :)

Answer (score 1):

Using your query, and this fact

1. answers get the value of it's question's ID in the column of parent

The requirement

> a second column called par, where all questions will get a value of 1.

becomes trivial, and seems to confirm with your data.

```
select id, parent, faq, 
(select count(*) from faq_table where parent = 
(select id from faq_questions) group by id) 
 as reply,
if(parent=0,1,0) as par
from faq_table
```

Basically when parent=0, it is a parent.  But since the comments state that there is only one table, then the above must be pseudo - the correct query should be

```
select id, parent, faq, 
   (select count(*) from faq_table t where t.parent = faq_table.id) as reply,
   case when parent = 0 then 1 else 0 end as par
from faq_table
```

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi, thanks for your reply Richard, I have just seen this.

Comment: I think he wants `par` to be `1` only if it has children. In the OP example row `21` has `par=0`, however your query will show `par=1`

Comment: @the I think you misread, it only states: `where all questions will get a value of 1.` It agrees with the data. parent=0 => par=1

Comment: @cyberkiwi Fair enough, but how do you explain the OP's "resulting table out of that query, I must get:"?

Comment: @the Am I missing something? The only par=1's are 19 and 22, where parent=0. `Which` table exactly are you looking at?

Comment: @cyberkiwi You are correct, i misread, guess its not good to roam the internet while drinking!

Answer (score 1):

This version also works;

```
SELECT q.id, q.parent, q.faq, count(a.id) AS reply, IF(ISNULL(a.id),0,1) as par
FROM faq_table q
LEFT JOIN faq_table a
  ON q.id = a.parent
  AND a.id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY q.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot

```
SELECT
    f.id,
    f.parent,
    f.faq,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM faq_table f2 WHERE f2.id = f.parent) AS reply
FROM faq f
```

Comment: Thanks nick, it's a great attempt, but it's adding a value of "1" in the same row as answer. I need to sum up the answers and to add that in the same row as question.

Comment: okay, it's done with reversing the logic simply :) like `f.id = f2.parent`

Comment: does that even pass syntax check?